# Zeromq XPUB/XSUB proxy only for subscription messages?

Tags: proxy, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I want to prevent subscribers from subscribing to all topics in ZeroMQ. My idea is to use an XPUB/XSUB proxy and drop subscriptions to all topics in the proxy. However, my concern is that all messages would go through the proxy in this case, not just the subscription messages. Wouldn't it be a performance issue? Is it possible to have only subscription messages to go through the proxy and regular messages directly between PUB/SUB sockets?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create something like you talk about with **`zmq`**, but it is beyond the scope of **`xsub/xpub`**. It's even almost beyond the scope of **`pub/sub`**.

By using the **`router`** and **`dealer`** you can build a protocol for doing this behavior, and in extreme cases it could be usable, maybe necessary.

But, my guess is it isn't a problem for you yet. If your not sending huge amounts of data, this will perform great for you. You could add multiple `xsub/xpub` servers and distribute the load by having each subscriber connect to different servers (load balancing). But again, only start engineering such setups when needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Are you saying that I shouldn't bother with preventing subscribers from subscribing to all topics, or that it should be fine with an XPUB/XSUB proxy dropping all subscriptions to all topics, even if all traffic will go through a proxy?

Comment: My last section of the answer focus on the performance question. I don't think you'll get see it. How much data do send? Like how many how many packages pr second, how big packages and how many subscribers?